# Exchanging elements (crossover) between two vectors

Tags: r, vector, bioinformatics, crossover

Assume I have:

`chromosome_1 <- c('0010000001010000')`

`chromosome_2 <- c('0100000001001010')`

How can I implement ***step 3-5*** ?

1. Evaluate

   - NC1 = no. of 1's in `chromosome_1`
   - NC2 = no. of 1's in `chromosome_2`
   - M = `min(NC1, NC2)`
2. Generate a random integer `NC` from `range(1, M)`
3. Randomly select `NC` gene positions among the genes
   with allele “1” from `chromosome_1` and form a set `s1` of indices of
   such selected positions.

   Randomly select `NC` gene positions among the genes
   with allele “1” from `chromosome_2` and form a set `s2` of indices of
   such selected positions.
4. `s = union(s1, s2)` **Assume** `s = 2, 3, 10, 15`
5. for each index `i` in `s`

   Exchange the alleles of chromosomes `chromosome_1` and `chromosome_2` at
   gene position `i`.

The following illustrates the outcome:

[image]

I would really really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the simplest solution, but it works

```
set.seed(12345)

## Step 1
a <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0)
b <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0)
m <- min(sum(a==1), sum(b==1))

## Step 2
random_int <- sample(1:m, 1)

## Step 3
random_a <- sample(which(a == 1), random_int)
random_b <- sample(which(b == 1), random_int)
#all <- sort(union(random_a, random_b))

## Step 4
## for demo purpose (assume it as the random output)
all <- c(2,3,10,15)     

temp_a <- a[all]
temp_b <- b[all]

## Step 5
##crossover
b[all] <- temp_a
a[all] <- temp_b

## Output
> a
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
> b
 [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [GA package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/GA.pdf):

In Manual (page 5), there is an example.

```
ga(type = c("binary", "real-valued", "permutation"),
fitness, ...,
min, max, nBits,
population = gaControl(type)$population,
selection = gaControl(type)$selection,
crossover = gaControl(type)$crossover,
mutation = gaControl(type)$mutation,
popSize = 50,
pcrossover = 0.8,
pmutation = 0.1,
elitism = base::max(1, round(popSize*0.05)),
updatePop = FALSE,
postFitness = NULL,
maxiter = 100,
run = maxiter,
maxFitness = Inf,
names = NULL,
suggestions = NULL,
optim = FALSE,
optimArgs = list(method = "L-BFGS-B",
poptim = 0.05,
pressel = 0.5,
control = list(fnscale = -1, maxit = 100)),
keepBest = FALSE,
parallel = FALSE,
monitor = if(interactive())
{ if(is.RStudio()) gaMonitor else gaMonitor2 }
else FALSE,
seed = NULL)
```

In example, population, selection, crossover, mutation and monitor operators assign new functions. In my study, I used own mutation and monitor functions. For example;

```
myga <- ga(type = "binary",
fitness, ...,
min, max, nBits,
mutation = myMutationFunction
popSize = 50,
pcrossover = 0.8,
pmutation = 0.1,
maxiter = 100,
run = maxiter,
monitor = myMonitorFunction

myMutationFunction <- function (x) {
#...
}

myMonitorFunction <- function (x) {
#...
}
```

So, you just define your own function and give the function name to ga function. In order to be reference, you can see default functions. You can see necessary parameters and return values in default functions.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I have edited my question to make things clear. Referring to page 21 of the manual, notice that the crossover function takes in two arguements, `object` and `parents`, what do they mean?